# iOS >> ShareKit: Twitter & Facebook & Email Doesn't Receive my App Store Link

Tags: ios, hyperlink, c-preprocessor, sharekit

I'm implementing **ShareKit** in my app; 
I defined in the **SHKConfig.h** the following definitions:

> > **#define SHKMyAppName @"MyAppName"**
> >
> > **#define SHKMyAppURL @"http://itunes.apple.com/app/myAppName/idMyAppID"**

When I share a link on **Twitter** or **Facebook** or **Email**, it doesn't publish my App Store App link. instead it publishes the following:

**Email** - No link at all:

---

[image]

---

**Facebook** - There is no link/image within the message like I would expect; instead, it only shows the message the user is writing - and the access to my app is from the unintuitive Facebook Get AppName link at the bottom of the feed:

---

[image]

---

**Twitter** - here it gives a strange notification saying I'm missing some sort of APIKEY that I couldn't find any definition on the ShareKit files to set:

---

[image]

---

and then on **Twitter Feed**:

---

[image]

---

Can anyone refer me to what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Dun know if u found an answer but just for future reference, it is caused because of sharekit trying to shorten urls for tweets using bit.ly . just get an api key for bit.ly and put it in the config file , this will go away.